# Notify all @SessionScoped-Beans-Instances from all Users

Tags: jsf, cdi

#### **My Problem**

I have a `@SessionScoped` `sessionInformationBean`, which holds a `Person`-Entity from a logged in user. So, if a User logs in, I am looking up the corresponding `Entity` and put in in the `@SessionScoped` CDI Bean. This Bean is used to retrieve the current user (a `Person`-Entity) at any position in code, so that you can check, if it is a Admin or things like that.

```
@Inject
private PersonFacade personFacade;

private Person currentUser;

public Person getCurrentUser() {
    if (currentUser == null) {
        String loginname = FacesContext.
        getCurrentInstance().
        getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();  
        currentUser = personFacade.findByLoginname(loginname);
    }

    return currentUser;
}
```

But set the case, an Admin is giving this logged in user ( the `Person`-Entity) some Admin-Rights and saves him to the database. In this case, the `Person` at the `@SessionScoped` Bean is not updated, therefore the already logged in user is not seeing his Admin-Rights after a refresh of his page. Thats the problem. To avoid this problem I am fetching the user new from the database every access (There is no cache activated) to the `@SessionScoped` bean.

#### What I want

But I want to cache him and avoid a database access every time.  So, I thought, if anyone saves a user, I will simply notice all `sessionInformationBean`-Instances and set the `currentUser`-Attribute to `null`. So, the next call, they fetch it again from database and cache it till its set to `null` again from my `Person.save()`-Operation.

#### What I tried

But that seems to be a little bit tricky. I thought I can handle it with CDI-Events, but they only will be pushed to the `sessionInformationBean` of the user, that is editing the other user.

Maybe something to do with my problem: [CDI Events observed across sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481921/do-cdi-events-observed-across-session-scoped-jsf-backing-beans?rq=1)

Then I thought.. okay.. lets do it with Primefaces-Push. But the same thing.. the Events are just coming to my own `sessionInformationBean`.

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
eventBus.publish("/session", "test");
```

I thought the purpose of push and WebSockets is to notify all users or sessions.

#### What should I do?

So, the question is: How to access all instances of a specific `@SessionScoped`Bean? I just want to access the `sessionInformationBean` from every logged in user and set the `currentUser`to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way I can think of to do this.  What I would recommend is to add an `ApplicationScoped` bean.  Whenever your `SessionScoped` bean is created, register it with this app scoped bean.  When you want to process this event iterate through all of these objects.

I'm curious though, what happens when you have multiple servers?